# When does this query gets generated?

Tags: oracle12c

When does this query get generated by the system?

```
DELETE FROM LBACSYS.LBAC$POLT WHERE TBL_NAME = UPPER(:B2 ) AND OWNER = UPPER(:B1 )
```

I googled it and found out that it is related to label security and nothing more.

Answer (score 0):

Deletes the entry from the table if both the table name and owner name match.

Answer (score 0):

It deletes all rows from `LBAC$POLT` table owned by `LBACSYS` whose

- column `tbl_name` is equal to value passed through the `b2` parameter (or a bind variable), converted to upper case
- column `owner` is eqal to value passed through `b1`, converted to upper case

For example:

```
SQL> select * from lbac$polt;

OWNER TABLE_NAME
----- ----------
SCOTT EMP
SCOTT DEPT
```

(this is a SQL*Plus client which uses substitution variables, e.g. `&b2`; your code uses bind variables; at the end, the result is just the same):

```
SQL> delete from lbac$polt where table_name = upper('&b2') and owner = upper('&b1');
Enter value for b2: emp
Enter value for b1: scott
old   1: delete from lbac$polt where table_name = upper('&b2') and owner = upper('&b1')
new   1: delete from lbac$polt where table_name = upper('emp') and owner = upper('scott')

1 row deleted.
```

Result:

```
SQL> select * from lbac$polt;

OWNER TABLE_NAME
----- ----------
SCOTT DEPT

SQL>
```